# how to find xml node by idref in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, idref

for example, I have simple xml

```
<A>
    <networks type="A">
        <hub id = "123">
            <port>8080</port>
        </hub>
        <client idref = "123">
            <host>some.value</host>
        </client>
    </networks>
</A>
<B>
    <networks type="B">
        <hub id = "235">
            <port>9090</port>
        </hub>
        <client idref = "235">
            <host>some.value</host>
        </client>
    </networks>
</B>
```

I iterate through network items/nodes using foreach loop with specific type.

```
 $networks = ($variable.SelectNodes('//networks') | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "$type*"})
foreach ($node in $networks) {
    if($node.hub -ne $null) {
        Write-Output 'hub:'
        Write-Output 'id' $node.hub.id
        Write-Output 'port' $node.hub.port
        Write-Output '*********'
    }
    if($node.client -ne $null) {
        Write-Output 'client:'
        Write-Output 'idref:' $node.client.idref
        Write-Output 'host:' $node.client.host 
        # how to pick port from networks//hub//port where hub.id = 123 by $node.client.idref here?
        Write-Output '**********'
    }
}
```

but when current node is "client", I need to distinguish port from "hub" tag by idref.
How to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is your desired output exactly?

Comment: @Theo, my attempt is to know what port is used for $node.client. I need to take it from $node.hub.port. I updated code, added comment. It should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but does this work?

```bsh
$xml = [xml] @"
<root>
    <A>
        <networks type="A">
            <hub id = "123">
                <port>8080</port>
            </hub>
            <client idref = "123">
                <host>some.value</host>
            </client>
        </networks>
    </A>
    <B>
        <networks type="B">
            <hub id = "235">
                <port>9090</port>
            </hub>
            <client idref = "235">
                <host>some.value</host>
            </client>
        </networks>
    </B>
</root>
"@

$networks = $xml.SelectNodes('//networks') 
foreach ($node in $networks) {
    if ($null -ne $node.hub) {
        Write-Output 'hub:'
        Write-Output 'id' $node.hub.id
        Write-Output 'port' $node.hub.port
        Write-Output '*********'
    }
    if ($null -ne $node.client) {
        Write-Output 'client:'
        Write-Output 'idref:' $node.client.idref
        Write-Output 'host:' $node.client.host 

        # how to pick port from networks//hub//port where hub.id = 123 by $node.client.idref here?
        Write-Output 'port: ' ($xml.SelectNodes('//networks') | Where-Object { $_.hub.id -eq $node.client.idref }).hub.port
        Write-Output "**********"  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this work, but it can be the case, when <hub> element can be in a different place in the xml, not in the same location with <client>

Comment: @Nikolas, I updated the answer based on your most recent comment.

Comment: what is the $_ object? it is null, when I use it